# different constraints for each row

Tags: modeling, r

I'm using the IpSolve package to solve a problem to optimize the assignment (minimum distance) between sellers (rows)and customers (columns) using Rstudio.

The problem I faced when using lp/lp.transport  is that I don't know how to introduce different constraints for each row. For example I want to establish that the sellers have between a minimum and a maximum number of customers, but as far as I know, I only can establish one constraint for each row.

Do you know how I can solve this ??

Do you know another more efficient way of solving this kind of problems when huge data is analyzed?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Would you please, elaborate more on the problem you have? Is it possible to share your math model to illustrate what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Basically my question is how to implement 2 or more constrains for each row in Rstudio using using lp/lp.transport. https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/lpSolve/html/lp.transport.html